# clang-format: ensure each interface field is on a new line for Typescript

Tags: typescript, clang-format

When I use clang-format with typescript, I get this output:

```js
export type IDimensions = {
  width: number; height : number;
};
```

What I want is:

```js
export type IDimensions = {
  width: number;
  height : number;
};
```